# Building a light framework is this approach worth developing?

Tags: javascript, css, utility

I am thinking about creating a Javascript library that parses each node in the DOMs' class attribute and looks for a namespace, once it finds the name space it parses the values following it (_ delimited values written into the classname string)

Here is the demo: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/rVwyQK

As you can see this particular proof of concept that it turns the classname padding_25px_25pct_25px_22px into ->

```
[elm]{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Here is the quick bit of JS code thrown together which could handle any similar structured DOM props but for simplicities sake, I left the method hard coded to deal with the padding property:

```
// Convention over configuration, dynamic style generator. Initialized and driven off of class name convention

(function inlineJs() {
  "use strict";
  var $paddingTarg = $('[class^="padding_"]');
  function replaceActionParseValues(action, subject){
    var res = subject.replace(action, '').replace('_', '').replace('pct', '%').split(/_/g); // % is invalid css selector value, so parse pct as the val and convert to a %
    return res;
  };
  $paddingTarg.each(function() {
    var dimsFullClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if (dimsFullClass.match('padding')) {
      var dims = replaceActionParseValues('padding', dimsFullClass)

      applyDims(dims.length);

      function applyDims(nDims) {

        switch (nDims) {

          case 1:
            $paddingTarg.css({
              'padding': dims[0]
            });
          break;

          case 2:
            $paddingTarg.css({
              'paddingTop': dims[0],
              'paddingRight': dims[1],
              'paddingBottom': dims[0],
              'paddingLeft': dims[1]
            });
          break;

          case 4:
            $paddingTarg.css({
              'paddingTop': dims[0],
              'paddingRight': dims[1],
              'paddingBottom': dims[2],
              'paddingLeft': dims[3]
            });
          break;

          default:
            throw new Error('Unknown param length sent to $.applyDims()');

        }
      }

    }
  });
})();
```

Is this approach right? Would these 'helpers' end up littering the DOM with the wrong type of naming amongst classes? To me it seems like this has all the speed of inline styling with all the shared code benefits of using a centralized not-inline stylesheet. I just want to be sure before I invest any dev time into making this into an open source utility.

Thanks to anyone who can lead me in the right direction on this, didn't know where to start, didn't see anything that was similar to this on SO.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: this is way too broad of a question or too opinionated.

Comment: Seems that bad css naming conventions are not a matter of opinion... this is a Science no? I just cant find the 100% finite rule that I can compare my convention against. I see similar self explanatory class names in several css libs.

Comment: That has no relevance to my post... did you even bother to read the code to see what it does? Its not inline style rules, its dynamically generated style classes... not something Ive ever seen before. Can you please tell me how your link has any similarity @asawyer? Try being right before being rude next time maybe. Its also a snippet, proof of concept as stated in the OP...

Comment: @AlphaG33k The main reason I'd think that is that there doesn't seem to be anything here promote using this above [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for CSS generation. (Also I agree that it was rude, deleted sorry)

Comment: Yes I use SASS and LESS, doesnt mean this may not end up being a better way... no problem I would see how this would be a waste of time if it used inline styles to do its work

Comment: I dont know if this is a definitive answer but https://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/ seems to say that although this is almost the right convention it is much too specific. Maybe I can apply some language wrapper around it so that it will translate to the overall look of the elem instead of listing the props and numeric values right inline.